# How to Read textFile based on another textFile 1st column as a KEY

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 TextFiles A and B

I want have read file A into Spark next I have to read file B also but depends on key I have to read

1. table A

   ### id column

1    anu
2     usha

2 Table B

### id   age

1    23 
2    23

---

I want load data based on 1st table 1st column as a key Like Foreign key and Primary Key Any one please Guide me-

Comment: what is the spark version used in your setup?

Comment: "I want have read file A into Spark", what is to "want read"? What does it mean to read something "into Spark"?

Answer (score 0):

form the gist of your question it seems you are trying to join to text files. You can use dataframes to joins this two files.

```
val table1 = sqlContext.read.format("text").load("/user/chlr/spark_test/table1.csv").map(x => x.getString(0).split(',').head -> x.getString(0).split(',').tail.head ).toDF("id","column")

val table2 = sqlContext.read.format("text").load("/user/chlr/spark_test/table2.csv").map(x => x.getString(0).split(',').head -> x.getString(0).split(',').tail.head ).toDF("id","column")

table1.join(table2, "id").show()
+---+------+------+
| id|column|column|
+---+------+------+
|  1|   anu|    23|
|  2|  usha|    23|
+---+------+------+
```